# I can't access wp url parameter

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm trying to add an url parameter to a custom wp rest api endpoint, but when I access the endpoint using this url: mysite.com/wp-json/booking/pris?name=carl, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_route_for_price' );

function my_register_route_for_price() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'name' );
    
    register_rest_route( 'booking', 'pris', array(
                    'methods' => 'GET',
                    'callback' => 'get_price_callback',
                )
            );
}

function get_price_callback() {
    $param = $request->get_url_params( 'name' );
    return rest_ensure_response($param);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a WordPress security feature.

Undefined WordPress query variable outside the scope of the `WP_Query` class need to be defined first.

> ### `WP::add_query_var( string $qv )`
>
> Adds a query variable to the list of public query variables.

### Use Case Scenario

---

```
<?php

add_action( 'init','wp67408336' );

function wp67408336() {

  global $wp;

  $wp->add_query_var( 'name' );

};
```

### In any case

---

```
<?php

$name = htmlspecialchars( $_GET["name"] );
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add the two lines to my code, but I get the same message. I have edited the code above.

Comment: Updated the answer, you should be able to use `$_GET["name"]`. And i'm not sure your error is related to that.